# Using <mat-icon> in innerHTML does not work

Tags: angular

I am trying to display strings containing `<mat-icon>` from my component, and having problem rendering them. The regular HTML elements, like bold, show fine, but not the mat-icon, which only shows the name. Any idea how to do it?

component.cs

`this.info = "Press <mat-icon>cloud_download</mat-icon> <b>Download</b> button."`

component.html

`<p innerHTML={{info}}>{{info}}</p>`

Result

Press cloud_download **Download**

Comment: Correct, because the angular component renderer / initializer does not trigger when you are injecting innerhtml.

Answer (score 21):

You could try using a `span` with the material-icons class. Eg: `<span class="material-icons">cloud_download</span>`

As far as I recall it won't render exactly the same as a mat-icon but quite similar, and probably more suitable for embedding in text

Comment: Very clever, but the correct class is "material-icons"

Comment: Just checked, and you're right - thanks for pointing that out! Edited the answer to correct

Comment: Very helpful, two years later. This should be marked ass the answer.

Comment: 2022 and this answer saved my day, thank you @Michael

Comment: Working good, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this and try again :

```
<p innerHTML="{{info}}">{{info}}</p>
```

You should use either `innerHTML="{{action.content}}"` or `[innerHTML]="action.content"` but not `[innerHTML]="{{action.content}}"` or `innerHTML={{action.content}}`

Comment: Even if stylistically your advice is sound, it does not bring a different result.

Comment: @Nightrain Where to you initialize the "this.info" variable?

Comment: It can come from the same component or be updated via a service from another component.

Comment: Did you try to initialize it before the view?

Comment: As it's coming from a service, it will be picked up in constructor or onInit: this.upload.currentInfoMsg.subscribe( message => this.info = message );

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite late to the party, but you could make the below work or you I'm sure.
Just wrap whatever other HTML you have around the below.

```
<mat-icon [innerHTML]="item.icon"></mat-icon>
```

Like:

```
<p>Hello, <mat-icon [innerHTML]="item.icon"></mat-icon>!</p>
```